# Make object visible when intersecting with target path of curve modifier

Tags: python, modifiers, shader-nodes, visibility, curve-modifier

I am creating an animation of a laser pulse traveling down a waveguide. To represent the laser pulse, I am using a long cylinder-like object with an emissive shader. To make the pulse follow the waveguide, I have defined a Bezier curve which determines the path the light travels, and have applied a curve modifier to the cylinder with `Deform Axis` set to X and the `Curve Object` target set as the waveguide curve. By varying the X position of the cylinder, I can make the object follow the waveguide path, as shown in the attached gif.

[image]

I would like to modify the object's shader so that it is visible/emissive only in the section of the object which is overlapping with the curve which is the `Curve Object`. So if the curve is 3 units long, only `0 <= point_on_object.x <= 3` is emissive. Normally I would do `Geometry.Position -> Separate XYZ.X -> >=0 and <=3` and attach this to a `Mix Shader` node. However, I need `point_on_object.x` to refer to the parametric, curve-deformed coordinate of x, not the actual geometric coordinate in real space, so I'm not sure what input to use here.

Also, because I am creating most of this animation programmatically (the full animation will have many waveguides and many laser pulses), the shader method needs to be fully automatic, so should will fetch whatever `cylider.modifiers.curve.curve_object.splines[0].calc_length()` is to determine the range of parametric x coordinates which are visible. Ideally, the solution should also not require creating a separate instance of the material for each unique curve, because I am creating many linked duplicates of a single master object which represents the light pulse for efficiency reasons, as there will be potentially hundreds of waveguides and thousands of light pulses in the animation.

Comment: what is a waveguide?

Comment: By 'Overlap' , do you mean 'Within the length of', but still bleeding light radially?

Comment: @Chris a waveguide is a structure that guides light (or other waves), such as a fiber optic cable.

Comment: @RobinBetts by overlapping I mean that the center axis of the curve-deformed is collinear with the path which it is following. If we define $z$ to be the extrusion axis of the cylinder with motion animated over time $t$ and $s(z(t))$ to be the path of the curve, I would like for the surface vector $\vec{r} = (x,y,z)$ of the cylinder to be shaded with emissive shaders whenever $(0,0,z(t))$ is in the domain of $s(z(t))$.